# React native typescript: usecontext functions not firing from inside child component

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, use-context

I have an issue when i try to use functions from a context inside a child component in a React native android app.

Below is my code for the context, and the form component im using it in (stripped down for brevity).

The "isFormOpen" object can be read no problem from inside any children that is wrapped in the provider, but when i try to call the "toggleForm" function from the same child component, it does nothing, no console errors either.

I have another context which is identical in structure and syntax except for vairable and function names etc, and that works perfectly, so im a bit confused as to why this does not work. I removed the other context, thinking there might be some type of conflict, but didnt solve it.

**AccountContext.tsx**

```
import React, { FC, createContext, useContext, useState } from 'react';

interface AccountContextType {
    isFormOpen: boolean,
    toggleForm: (toggle: boolean) => void
};

export const AccountContext = createContext<AccountContextType>({
    isFormOpen: false,
    toggleForm: () => null
});

export const AccountContextProvider: FC = props => {
    const [formOpen, setFormOpen] = useState<boolean>(false);

    const toggleForm = (toggle: boolean) => {
        setFormOpen(toggle);
    }

    const value: AccountContextType = {
        isFormOpen: formOpen,
        toggleForm
    }

    return (
        <AccountContext.Provider value={value}>
            {props.children}
        </AccountContext.Provider>
    )
}

export const useAccountContext = () => useContext(AccountContext);
```

**TrackUploadForm.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-paper';

import { useAccountContext } from '../contexts/AccountContext';
import { AccountContextProvider } from '../contexts/AccountContext';

const TrackUploadForm = () => {
    const accountContext = useAccountContext();

    return (
        <AccountContextProvider>
            <SafeAreaView>
                <Button onPress={() => accountContext.toggleForm(false)} mode='outlined'>Cancel</Button>
            </SafeAreaView>
        </AccountContextProvider>
    )
};

export default TrackUploadForm;
```

Answer (score 1):

1. `useAccountContext` is called outside the provider

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <AccountContextProvider>
      <Content />
    </AccountContextProvider>
  );
}

const Content = () => {
  const accountContext = useAccountContext();
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>{accountContext.isFormOpen ? "true" : "false"}</h1>
      <Button onPress={() => accountContext.toggleForm(false)} mode='outlined'>Cancel</Button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

2. `accountContext.toggleForm(false)` <-- always false, change it to `accountContext.toggleForm(!accountContext.isFormOpen)`

Together we have
https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-panini-yo129

Comment: Oh wow, that worked. The reason i didnt think it would, is because i did move the wrapper way up in the tree but just not as far as wrapping the whole app. I was under the impression that you could wrap whichever component you want and all its children could use the context, and that the point of it was to only allow certain components to use the context.

Thank you.